# Weblogic cannot get last page

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, tomcat, weblogic

Hope you can help me.

I was using tomcat as an application server for my Spring/Jsp project. I've implemented the javascript section within the jsp page so that whenever I've received an error from the database I would use the command `history.go(-1)` to go back to the previous page (i.e., the page with all its data prior to submission) . All this was working fine until I switched to weblogic.

When I now use the `history.go(-1)` command I get no page (or rather a blank page).

Can anyone tell me if there is a weblogic parameter that will allow the page to be cached so I can go backwards using the `history.go(-1)` command?

Is there another solution I am unaware of?

Many thanks in advance,
cq